# Why C# (.NET Core 3) can't choose the right overload for MemoryExtensions.IndexOf?

Tags: c#, .net-core

The snippet is to rebuild a binary tree from its pre-order and in-order representation.

```cs
static public BinaryTreeNode<T> BuildFromPreAndInOrder<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> preOrder, ReadOnlySpan<T> inOrder)
{
    if (preOrder == null || preOrder.IsEmpty || inOrder == null || inOrder.IsEmpty) { return null; }
    var val = preOrder[0];
    BinaryTreeNode<T> root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(val);
    // this doesn't make sense
    var splitPoint = MemoryExtensions.IndexOf<T>(inOrder, val);
    if (splitPoint == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    preOrder = preOrder.Slice(1);
    var leftPart = inOrder.Slice(0, splitPoint);
    var rightPart = inOrder.Slice(splitPoint + 1);
    root.left = BuildFromPreAndInOrder(preOrder, leftPart);
    root.right = BuildFromPreAndInOrder(preOrder, rightPart);
    return root;
}
```

The node is simple so I attach the partial.

```cs
class BinaryTreeNode<T> : IEquatable<BinaryTreeNode<T>>
{
    public T key;
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> left;
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> right;
}
```

I tried to compile it on .NET Core 3 Preview 7 SDK but the compiler complains `error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'T' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<T>'`. Why the compiler can't choose the right method?
The inspection tool shows me a signature that should be able to match this.

```cs
public static int IndexOf<T>([NullableAttribute(new[] { 0, 1 })] this ReadOnlySpan<T> span, [NullableAttribute(1)] T value) where T : IEquatable<T>;
```

Comment: Have you tried with `SpanExtensions`? Is it available?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `where T : IEquatable<T>` constraint on your method, so no overload of `IndexOf` is actually applicable. Add that and the problem disappears.

The actual error is still misleading/wrong. This is change/regression in Roslyn. A change between error messages can be observed going from C# 7.2 to 7.3; for 7.2 you'll get

> error CS0314: The type `T` cannot be used as type parameter `T` in the
>   generic type or method ... There is no boxing
>   conversion or type parameter conversion from `T` to
>   `System.IEquatable<T>`.

Whereas 7.3 gives the far less useful

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from `FirstParamType` to
>   `SecondParamType`.

This is not specific to .NET Core or `ReadOnlySpan`, it can be repro'd with any generic class. It might possibly be [fixed in the next release](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/37613) (disclaimer: I didn't check if the fix actually applies, but it seems to address exactly this issue).